# Convert GameCenterManager to ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting, game-center

Im using the GameCenterManger from Apple's GKTapper demo. I decided I want to convert my project to arc, but I keep getting an error saying "GameCenterManager.h:67:43: The current deployment target does not support automated __weak references". Any help would be appreciated, thanks!
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GKTapper/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Change your deployment target to iOS 5 which supports weak references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Weak" not support iOS 4.0 target.

1st way...
if your project is newer. change target to iOS 5.0 or later.

2nd way...
You should support iOS 4.0.
You can use assign keyword.
But assign do not support setting to nil.